# How to remove the Pyramid debug toolbar

Tags: python, pyramid, pyramid-debug-toolbar

I removed the row with `pyramid_debugtoolbar` from the `development.ini` file as suggested [here](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/quick_tutorial/debugtoolbar.html#analysis), but it still shows up.

How do I disable it?

Answer (score 3):

To quote the source you linked:

> When you want to disable this toolbar, there's no need to change code: you can remove it from `pyramid.includes` in the relevant `.ini` configuration file

So if you removed the lines 3-4 in your `development.ini` as indicated, then stopped and restarted your app as before, then the toolbar should no longer appear.

Comment: That's what I expected, but the toolbar is still there

Comment: I bet you edited the wrong `.ini`. Make sure that you changed the `.ini` file for the app that you are running and visit in the web browser. I just ran a cookiecutter to generate a new project, disabled the toolbar as instructed, and the toolbar icon vanished when I restarted my app.